# Call super class constructor when multiple inheritance in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo, multiple-inheritance

I have an object that inherit from 2 others object.

I'm using manually call for constructor because i want to manipulate the parameters i am sending to the super classes (see `'-chains-'`)

```
define([...], function(...) {
   return declare("myClass", [base1, base2],
   {
      "-chains-":
    {
        constructor: "manual"
    },

    constructor: function (params) {
        this.inherited(arguments, [ params.x, params.y, ... ]); // just for the example
    }
   });
});
```

The problem is that I am doing something wrong here with the syntax because my super classes constructors are not being called at all.

When i'm removing the `-chains-` and the `this.inherited...` the super classes constructors are being called but without my parameters manipulation.

**Found Workaround**

Instead of the `this.inherited(...)` in `myClass` constructor we write

```
base1.prototype.constructor.apply(this, [paramsForBase1]);
base2.prototype.constructor.apply(this, [paramsForBase2]);
```

But still happy to hear the Dojo way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Dojo way I'm afraid. The main advantage of automatic constructor inheritance is that it will call all constructors.

However, if you set it to manual, then it will **only** call the constructor of the **last** inherited class in the list. In your case, the constructor of `base2` will be called, but not the one from `base1`.

The reason for this is that eventually, your class can only have one method of each kind, so if both `base1` and `base2` have the same method, then it will override them in the same order you provided the inheritance array. Meaning that it will first contain `base1.constructor`, and in the next step it will be overriden by `base2.constructor`.

---

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to manually call the constructors of all base classes by yourself, you could create a loop. All base constructors are actually available in a meta object. It's a bit hacky, but `this.constructor._meta.parents` provides an array of all constructors, so you can simply loop over it, for example:

```
var inheritAllConstructors = function(object, arguments) {
    for (var idx = 0; idx < object.constructor._meta.parents.length; idx++) {
        object.constructor._meta.parents[idx].apply(object, arguments);
    }
};
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
constructor: function(name) {
    inheritAllConstructors(this, ["custom", "arguments"]);
},
```

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7wnvbu1/

Comment: Sounds perfect sense.. Thanks. Workaround it is :)

Comment: If you don't want to manually call all the constructors, there's still a way to retrieve an array of all parents and loop over them using `this.constructor._meta.parents`. It's still a bit reusable then. I edited my answer with additional details.

Comment: Yes, I've digged into dojo and saw those members.. But i don't like using undeclared members of any library for the case that one day they will change/remove it with newer versions and then i will have to deal with it again. But thank you very much, you've great help